# user-defined attribute on element

Tags: jquery, css

how can you put a user-defined attribute on a html element and then find the element with jquery?

```
var btn_edit = $('<input class="my_class" userattribute="test" type="button" value="edit" />');
```

have read about something i CSS where you can do something like this

```
.my_class[userattribute='test']{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve it with the `attr()` method like this:

`btn_edit.attr('userattribute')`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/59SQC/

Note that if you are gonna be using your own custom attributes, you should prepend them with `data-`

**edit**

You can find the element which has it set using:

`$('*[userattribute]');`

and get the value of it:

`$('*[userattribute]').attr('userattribute')`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/2n2hb/

and if you want to select the elements with the attribute set to a specific value:

`$('*[userattribute="test"]').attr('userattribute')`

Comment: how can you then get find the element where the attribute is set?

Comment: -1 because you did not answer the whole question. He asked how to set and get the attribute :)

Comment: I want to find the input element with the attribute in a row in a table

Comment: @Craig he asked how you can set one on an element **and then find it with jquery**, from which your answer does neither based on the code he provided.

Comment: if I want to find it in a specific row and click it..? $('*[userattribute]', row).click();

Comment: @Niklas: note that you should use quotes for the attribute value in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element which has certain value in the attribute it would be:

```
$("*[userattribute='test']");
```

Assuming it's value is "test"

If what you want is to get the element that has the attribute set (as you said in your comment "how can you then get find the element where the attribute is set?") but you don't know the value then you should do:

```
$("*[userattribute!='']");
```